# Generating XML file out of Excel with 50k rows

Tags: excel, vba, xls

I am new to VBA. I know other programming languages a little. I would be interested to know, how to transfer the table below into a new structure the most efficient way. In total there are 50k rows of data to process and I would need to know which approach could work given the amount of data.

**Excel:**

```
Level   Key     Value                   Reference

1       K_1     Fruit   
1       K_2     Vegetable   
2       K_1_1   Banana                  K_1
2       K_1_2   Apple                   K_1
2       K_2_1   Cucumber                K_2
2       K_2_2   Carrot                  K_2
3       K_1_1_1 Banana Something        K_1_1
3       K_1_1_2 Banana Something else   K_1_1
3       K_1_1_3 Banana Something else   K_1_1
3       K_1_1_4 Banana Something else   K_1_1
3       K_1_1_5 Banana Something else   K_1_1
```

The resulting structure should then be to group the types, subtypes and subsubtypes according to the structure below:

```
<Type key="K_1">
    <LevelID>1</LevelID>
    <Value>Fruit</Value>
    <SubType key="K_1_1">
        <LevelID>2</LevelID>
        <Value>Banana</Value>
        <Subsubtype key="K_1_1_1">
            <LevelID>3</LevelID>
            <Value>Banana something</Value>
        </Subsubtype>
        <Subsubtype key="K_1_1_2">
            <LevelID>3</LevelID>
            <Value>Banana something else</Value>
        </Subsubtype>
    </SubType>
    <SubType key="K_1_2">
        <LevelID>2</LevelID>
        <Value>Apple</Value>
        <Subsubtype key="K_1_1_1">
            <LevelID>3</LevelID>
            <Value>Apple something</Value>
        </Subsubtype>
        <Subsubtype key="K_1_1_2">
            <LevelID>3</LevelID>
            <Value>Apple something else</Value>
        </Subsubtype>
    </SubType>
</Type>
```

The biggest challenge to me is to handle the amount of data the most efficient way.

Comment: Is your specific goal to create an XML file, and do you need to do this with VBA/code? BTW the fourth column seems redundant.

Comment: The 4th column is needed to know what the line refers to. E.g. K_2_1 Cucumber is a Vegetable K_2. Creating an XML file is the last bit. That I do know how to create and properly safe in UTF-8. But bringing the flat structure into the model structure.